# How to minimize webpage in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless, minimize

How can I minimize the browser window using selenium in python language?
I use Chrome.

--Headless and driver.minimize_window() doesn't work for me.
When I use driver.minimize_window(), it minimizes the browser but my code won't go any further.
I used browser.set_window_position(-900, 950) and it's working fine, but I'd like to be able to minimize, not move and hide the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Install the package **keyboard**. And Try like this

```
from selenium import webdriver
import keyboard

# Set up Chrome options
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Optional: Ensure the window is maximized initially
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)

# Create a Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Navigate to a URL (replace with your URL)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

# Minimize the browser window using keyboard shortcut
keyboard.press_and_release("win+down")  # Minimize the window on Windows

# Add a delay to give time for the window to minimize
driver.implicitly_wait(2)

# Perform other actions or navigate further
# ...

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer worked, thank you. Just the option part is wrong, If you make the browser to be maximize, the keyboard.press_and_release("win+down") will only make the browser smaller not minimized. But if you don't force it to start in maximized window, there will be no problem.

Comment: It didn't work. When I minimize the browser in any way, the code won't go further and it needs to be up and in my face.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to use the official API doc from selenium.
There is command for such operation.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#minimize-window

Select the specific language from tabs, in your case should be:

```
driver.minimize_window()
```

Comment: that won't work, as I mentioned in my question, I have tried that. It minimizes the webpage but the program won't go any further.